# React JS mapped array - render a single item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a React front end, which renders an array of rows based on objects from an API. I am mapping the object array, which works as intended. If the condition is met, an icon button is displayed. If the condition of the child elements below (sector.properties.length === 0) is true multiple times, multiple buttons will be rendered in the row. I am trying to only display a single button if the condition is true, but am struggling to figure it out.

```
{data.sectors.map((sector, index) => (
    <SingleLineCell
      key={`${data.productName}Product${index}`}
    >
      {sector.properties.length === 0 && (
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => 
            showModal('DeleteData', {
              form: data,
              onConfirmDelete: () => {
                onConfirmDelete(data);
              }
            })
          }
        >
          <IconDelete responsive />
          <span className="sr-only">Delete {data.productName} Product</span>
        </button>
      )}
    </SingleLineCell>
  ))}
```

So this is what is currently rendered. I want to only render the first button, even when the condition is true multiple times:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `map` is just used to display this button then instead of `map` use first `some` to check if the data satisfies the condition and then just print the button.

```js
{data.sectors.some((sector) => sector.properties.length === 0) && (
    <SingleLineCell
      key={`${data.productName}Product`}
    >
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => 
          showModal('DeleteData', {
            form: data,
            onConfirmDelete: () => {
              onConfirmDelete(data);
            }
          })
        }
      >
        <IconDelete responsive />
        <span className="sr-only">Delete {data.productName} Product</span>
      </button>
    </SingleLineCell>
)}
```